# How can I get the response code from a VolleyError?

Tags: java, android, networking, httpresponse, android-volley

I'm looking for a way to get the response code of a thrown VolleyError. My ErrorListener looks like this:

```
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
        //Get response code here
        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.toString());
        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
};
```

The 2 lines I send to my VolleyLog print the following:

```
03-12 10:57:56.932: E/Volley(7147): [1] 1.onErrorResponse: Error: 
03-12 10:57:56.932: E/Volley(7147): [1] 1.onErrorResponse: Error:
```

Volley does know what comes back because I can also see the following in my VolleyLog:

```
03-12 10:57:56.692: E/Volley(7147): [41854] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://*******/Employee/authenticate
03-12 10:57:56.897: E/Volley(7147): [41854] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://*******/Employee/authenticate
03-12 10:57:56.902: W/System.err(7147): com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
03-12 10:57:56.902: W/System.err(7147):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:143)
03-12 10:57:56.902: W/System.err(7147):     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
```

So basically, what I want is to get that response code "403" (Forbidden).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

through the VolleyError:

```
error.networkResponse.statusCode
```

looking at the source code, I saw that VolleyError has a public final member `NetworkResponse` called `networkResponse`, that holds that `statusCode` of the Http call. You should check for NPE.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/volley/NetworkResponse.java) you can find the source code for the `NetworkResponse`.
 [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/com/android/volley/VolleyError.java#VolleyError) you can find the source code for the `VolleyError`